# Getting permission denied error when running cf command on mac os x

Tags: macos, cloud-foundry

I have installed Cloud Foundry CLI package on my Mac OS X Yosemite. From the terminal interface when I type `cf` command, I get the following error

```
FAILED
Error read/writing config:  open /Users/viyer/.cf/config.json: permission denied
```

How do I fix this? I can't find the file `config.json`.

Comment: Post the output of `ls -lR ~/.cf`.  Then it's probably `sudo chmod -R u+w ~/.cf`.

Answer (score 12):

I found that removing the .cf directory then running the cf cli fixed it

```
sudo rm -r ~/.cf
cf -h
```

Comment: This solves a similar "Error read/writing config:  unexpected end of JSON input"  in windows

Answer (score 2):

That was a bit weird, but I solved it by assigning 777 permission to the folder and config.json.

So, `sudo chmod 777 .cf/config.json` resolved the problem in my case.

Give it a try!

Cheers!

Comment: No no no no no. Don't just change the permissions to 777. This is equal to locking yourself out of your house and just smashing the door. You can get in now but so can anyone else. StackOverflow is full of people saying to use 777 but I have yet to see a case were it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `cf` CLI will try to create and write to a directory named `.cf` in the user's home directory (i.e. `~/.cf`). For some reason the user on your machine doesn't have permissions to create and/or write to that directory.

You can work around this problem by setting the `CF_HOME` environment variable to another directory that the user does have permissions in.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no amount of changing permissions on my El Capitan would enable cf to access the config.json file in the .cf folder. I created a new folder in my home space ("CLI") and ensured it had the right permissions and set CF_HOME to point to "~/CLI/" . Just creating the new CF_HOME folder and setting CF_HOME in my .bash.profile was insufficient. I then copied the contents of the .cf folder into my new CLI folder. Finally! cf is working!

Oh, this is interesting. CF on this version of OSX will only run from the home directory, it won't run (it won't find config.json) from anything other than root.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/{username}/.cf`

It worked for me on OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

The config.json need to have read and write permissions, in my case the .cf folder has root as owner and staff as group, my user on my Mac Yosemite is part of the group staff, but still the config.json file has permission set to 600 
**to fix this problem you should do:**

`sudo chmod 666 /User/YourUser/.cf/config.json`

Also check the permissions of the .cf folder and check if you can read and write. Do something like this: `sudo chmod 755 /User/YourUser/.cf`

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the .cf folders from your system and try again. This is something which @broomyocymru has already mentioned above. But still felt this might help users who might not be familiar with shell commands